# Why is Gmail API returning Bad Request failedPrecondition error using JWT?

Tags: node.js, jwt, gmail-api

I'm seeing a lot of older questions but nothing seems to address my issue.

I'm using Node. I've followed the Google documentation and everything that I can think of checking seems to be order.

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const gmail = google.gmail('v1');
const privatekey = require('../privatekey.json');

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      privatekey.client_email,
      null,
      privatekey.private_key, 
      ['https://mail.google.com/'],
      null
      );

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error from Auth ', err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected!");
        gmail.users.messages.list({
            auth: jwtClient,
            userId: 'theGmailUser.com' //This isn't the service account user 
        });
    }
});
```

I do get "Successfully connected!" but then it throws the "failedPrecondition". I can't figure this out.

Comment: What happens if you place the authorized service account email in place of the 'theGmailUser.com'?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well and it didn't work either. I sure wish the documentation was better.